# Arquillian Beforesuite Unittest Preparation

Tags: java, unit-testing, jboss-arquillian

I want to call a Method before any arquilliantest. I created a Suite by Inheritance. See [Suite class inheritance](http://discuss.arquillian.org/t/arquillian-core-suite-subsuite-how-to-define-the-suite/163/4)

My Suite class looks like this:

```
public class ProvisioningITestSuite extends RdpArquillianTest {

    @Inject
    private PathConfigForTest pathConfig;

    public void prepareDirsForProvisioningTests(@Observes BeforeSuite event) throws IOException {
        Files.newDirectoryStream(pathConfig.getVdfsTargetBwkSignalOutputDir().toPath()).forEach(file - >{
            try {
                Files.delete(file);
            } catch(IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        });

        Files.newDirectoryStream(pathConfig.getVdfsTargetPrdCompleteSupplyDir().toPath()).forEach(file - >{
            try {
                Files.delete(file);
            } catch(IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

How can i get this to work? Arquillian is very new to me, am I on the right way?

Comment: i know the method is not very nice code, i just implemnted this quick and dirty...

Answer (score 0):

The thread you stumbled upon is a dev discussion about overall suite support which is not released yet.

I would suggest using simple `@Before` method with the same logic if you are using JUnit.